# Why there is an Internal error: instance signatures not found for class java.lang.String when using JIBX BindGen tool?

Tags: jibx

I just downloaded the jibx 1.2.6, when I try the "bindgen" target in examples/bindgen, I got an Internal error: instance signatures not found for class java.lang.String. What's the reason and how to fix it?
The script of the build.xml is:

```
 <!-- generate default binding and schema -->
```

```
<echo message="Running BindGen tool"/>
<java classpathref="classpath" fork="true" failonerror="true"
    classname="org.jibx.binding.generator.BindGen">
  <arg value="-s"/>
  <arg value="${basedir}/src"/>
  <arg value="org.jibx.starter1.Order"/>
</java>
```

and the error shows below:

```
bindgen:
 [echo] Running BindGen tool
 [java] Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Internal error: instance signatures not found for class java.lang.String
 [java]     at org.jibx.binding.model.ClassWrapper.isImplements(ClassWrapper.java:135)
 [java]     at org.jibx.custom.classes.SharedValueBase.fillType(SharedValueBase.java:367)
 [java]     at org.jibx.custom.classes.ValueCustom.fillDetails(ValueCustom.java:316)
 [java]     at org.jibx.custom.classes.ClassCustom.apply(ClassCustom.java:800)
 [java]     at org.jibx.custom.classes.GlobalCustom.addClassCustomization(GlobalCustom.java:377)
 [java]     at org.jibx.binding.generator.BindGen.isValueClass(BindGen.java:134)
 [java]     at org.jibx.binding.generator.BindGen.expandReferences(BindGen.java:225)
 [java]     at org.jibx.binding.generator.BindGen.findReferences(BindGen.java:1010)
 [java]     at org.jibx.binding.generator.BindGen.generate(BindGen.java:1124)
 [java]     at org.jibx.binding.generator.BindGen.main(BindGen.java:1302)
```

BTY, the "compile" target runs successfully, and the JDK I use is 1.8.

Answer (score 1):

Jason,

JIBX 1.2.6 does not work with jdk 1.8.

I'm currently working on the next version which will be compatible.
I'll see if I can post the beta version tonight.
Check the sourceforge site to download the new version.

Cheers!

Don

JiBX contributor

Comment: Thanks Don. I'll try to use JDK 1.7, and update the result later. Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks Don. It works well on JDK 7. Looking forward for the new version.